# Firebase custom domain name for database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can we change domain name to custom domain? 
for example :

> appname.firebaseio.com to appname.mydomain.com

i know we can do it for hosting:

> appname.firebaseapp.com to appname.mydomain.com

Just wondering if it can be done for firebase database also.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use your own domain for accessing the Firebase Database.

Comment: Has this changed recently?

Comment: Nope, nor is it unlikely to change. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Can I proxy it somehow?