# How to mask firebase db dns with a custom domain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-realtime-database

Let say i have a firebase db at `https://vivid-fire-id.firebaseio.com/`.

So the browser will try to connect to `vivid-fire-id.firebaseio.com` particular domain.

Is there way to add a custom domain from which the db is accessed from?
For eg: `https://firebase.mydomain.com`

This is required to make sure that firewalls do not create problem while access our application.

Comment: That is currently not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066775/firebase-custom-domain-name-for-database

Comment: Any workaround that can be used. Can we see this is near future

Answer (score 0):

api gateway can be one of possible solution. Google search reveals lot of info on api gateways
Treat firebase as a microservice.