# Changing Firebase Database URL

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use my own url to interact with my Firebase database REST API.  I understand that you cannot alter the default "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/" from within the app.  I am wondering if it is possible to do this externally through some form of url-rewriting?

If so, what are the elements required & are there any complications to overcome (particularly with https)?

Comment: create a api file, in that file you can use firebase url and fetch data, Your app can access your url which fetch data from firebase, if you wanna do ewrite url, you should be carefull in passing parameters and access token, should be done in HTTPS, to overcome the risk of security

Comment: There is no way to change the URL from which your Firebase Database is served. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066775/firebase-custom-domain-name-for-database

Comment: @Prags this would need to be run on an external server presumably? I am looking to have a public facing API where I don't want references to Firebase.

Comment: @Puffelen, I know - that's why I'm asking for external options.