# How to Hide part of URL?

Tags: firebase, url, firebase-realtime-database, hyperlink

Is there a way to hide part of the URL?

For example instead of https://progx.firebaseio.com/progx1.json

to show only https://progx/progx1.json

I am using this link in IFTTT's webhook to connect it with firebase and I don't want to expose/share the complete URL with others.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a custom URL for your Firebase Realtime Database. See [Use custom domain name as firebase database/auth/storage URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050225/use-custom-domain-name-as-firebase-database-auth-storage-url) and [Firebase custom domain name for database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066775/firebase-custom-domain-name-for-database)

If you want to simplify the URL, you will have to set up your own server on a custom/simpler domain. So your IFTTT then writes to that server, which in turn writes to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.